# How to ignore the splitting character in strings with Liquibase SQL syntax

Tags: sql, database, liquibase, database-versioning

I have this SQL script:

```
Insert into  DB_TABLE1 (N, B) values ('30','66');
Insert into  DB_EXECUTION (COMMAND)
VALUES ('/* Script generated at 20.04.2006 12:38:44 */


/* error_permissible = 955*/
Create Table map_encodekey
( privatekey VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL
);

/* error_permissible = 2260*/
Alter Table map_encodekey
  Add Constraint map_encodekey_pk
  Primary Key
   (privatekey);

commit;   

');
```

This script is executed by Liquibase, but it raises this error

> ...
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01756: quoted
>   string not properly terminated
>
> ...

The problem is that Liquibase splits the second insert statement when it finds the  ';' in the quoted string of the `DB_EXECUTION.COMMAND` field; in fact Liquibase doesn't interpret the SQL statements as SQL, but treats them as normal strings.

This is a problem, because I have to split the statements somehow because I have multiple insert statements in the same script (so the [splitStatements](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html) option is not an option for me) meanwhile I have to tell Liquibase to treat SQL strings as strings which start and end with single quotes.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you

Giulio

Comment: What version of Liquibase are you using? Newer versions have improved the SQL parsing some

Comment: Hi @Nathan. I'm using the Liquibase plugin at version 3.4.1

Comment: I opened a JIRA ticket for this. 
https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2556

I think it is a Oracle driver parsing problem, but you can help me understanding the problem more.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look